# Can I auto-fit the width of Graphviz nodes using dot?

Tags: graphviz, dot

Please does anyone know if there's a way to make Graphviz's `dot` program (note: not `neato`, although I'd also be somewhat interested in answers for that) auto-fit the width of nodes to accommodate the labels I specify? At the moment I have this

```
digraph
{
    node [shape=record];
    n [label="This is a very long caption"];
}
```

but the node ends up too small to accommodate the caption:

[image: Bad Graphviz output]

I found an option called `fixedsize`, which in theory I should be able to set to `false` in order to make the nodes expand to fit their labels:

http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:fixedsize

Unfortunately, it doesn't work, as this gives me the same result:

```
digraph
{
    node [shape=record, fixedsize=false];
    n [label="This is a very long caption"];
}
```

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The node label width in your example actually *does* auto-fit when using `dot`.

`fixedsize=false` (default) *and* any given value for [`width`](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d%3awidth) however should yield the given value for width if the output format is dot:

> Note also that, if the output format is dot, the value given to width
>   will be the final value.

There may be a problem with your version of graphviz - did you try using a recent version?

Comment: I saw that comment in the docs actually, although I have to say I then got the exact same behaviour when I tried it with neato. I think you're right that I should probably double-check to make sure my version of Graphviz is the latest one - will try it and report back.

Comment: I think the documentation refers to the [dot output format](http://www.graphviz.org/content/output-formats), not the layout engine creating the output. I'm not sure whether this means the label width will still be adapted when outputting for example to a png with a given width and `fixedsize=false`.

Comment: Very good call, it's the layout engine - it works fine with `-Tpdf`. Jolly odd if you ask me!

Comment: More specifically, it seems `-Tpng:gdiplus` suffers from the problem illustrated, whereas `-Tpng:cairo:gd` and `-Tpng:cairo:gdiplus` don't.